# How long does the event_loop live in a Django>=3.1 async view

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio

I am playing around with the new async views from Django 3.1.

Some benefits I would love to have is to do some simple fire-and-forget "tasks" after the view already gave its `HttpResponse`, like sending a push notification or sending an email.
I am not looking for solutions with third-party packages like celery!

To test this async views I used some code from this tutorial: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-async-views/

```py
async def http_call_async():
    for num in range(1, 200):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(num)
        
    # TODO: send email async
    print('done')


async def async_view(request):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(http_call_async())
    return HttpResponse("Non-blocking HTTP request")
```

I started the django server with uvicorn.

When I make a request to this view it will immediately return the HTTP-response "Non-blocking HTTP request".

In the meantime and after the HTTP-response, the event loop continues happily to print the numbers up to 200 and then print "done".

This is exactly the behaviour I want to utilize for my fire-and-forget tasks.

Unfortunatly I could not find any information about the lifetime of the event loop running this code.

How long does the event loop live?
Is there a timeout?
On what does it depend? On uvicorn? Is that configurable?

Are there any resources which discuss this topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django (which does not provide an ASGI server) does not limit the lifetime of the event loop.

In the case of this question:

- ASGI server: Uvicorn
- Event loop: either the built-in asyncio event loop or `uvloop` (both do not limit their lifetime)

For Uvicorn:

- **How long does the event loop live?**
  The event loop lives as long as the worker lives.
- **Is there a timeout?**
  No, tasks run until completion (unless the worker is unresponsive and is killed by Gunicorn).
- **On what does it depend? On Uvicorn?**
  Worker lifetime is mainly limited by `--limit-max-requests` (Gunicorn: `--max-requests`).

  - **Is that configurable?**
    Yes, but the worker still exits at some point. It may also be killed for other reasons.

See the issue for yourself by specifying `--limit-max-requests 2` and running the view twice:

```sh
uvicorn mysite.asgi:application --limit-max-requests 2
```

## Graceful shutdown

Regardless of how the lifetime is limited, what we might care about is how to handle a shutdown.

### How does Uvicorn do graceful shutdown?

Let's see how Uvicorn worker (`uvicorn.server.Server`) does graceful shutdown for requests.

> uvicorn.protocols.http.h11_impl.H11Protocol#__init__: Store a reference to server tasks
>
> ```py
> # Shared server state
> self.server_state = server_state
> self.tasks = server_state.tasks
> ```
>
> uvicorn.protocols.http.h11_impl.H11Protocol#handle_events: Add request task to tasks
>
> ```py
> self.cycle = RequestResponseCycle(
>     ...
> )
> task = self.loop.create_task(self.cycle.run_asgi(app))
> task.add_done_callback(self.tasks.discard)
> self.tasks.add(task)
> ```
>
> uvicorn.server.Server#shutdown: Wait for existing tasks to complete
>
> ```py
> if self.server_state.tasks and not self.force_exit:
>     msg = "Waiting for background tasks to complete. (CTRL+C to force quit)"
>     logger.info(msg)
>     while self.server_state.tasks and not self.force_exit:
>         await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
> ```

### How to make Uvicorn worker wait for your task?

Let's piggyback on this by adding your tasks to the server tasks.

```py
async def async_view(request):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.create_task(http_call_async())       # Replace this
    task = loop.create_task(http_call_async())  # with this
    server_state = await get_server_state()             # Add this
    task.add_done_callback(server_state.tasks.discard)  # Add this
    server_state.tasks.add(task)                        # Add this
    return HttpResponse("Non-blocking HTTP request")
```

```py
import gc
from uvicorn.server import ServerState

_server_state = None


@sync_to_async
def get_server_state():
    global _server_state
    if not _server_state:
        objects = gc.get_objects()
        _server_state = next(o for o in objects if isinstance(o, ServerState))
    return _server_state
```

Now, Uvicorn worker will wait for your tasks in a graceful shutdown.